# Fan speed auto control doesn't seem to work properly anymore (too high)

Tags: 12.04, fan, fancontrol

It's very annoying and I think it happened since last update, the fan of the CPU runs louder, that means probably faster than usual. It's really the CPU and not the NVIDIA fan. I already tried some things.

I modified grub config:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force acpi_osi=linux"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

I read that the first one is for buggy BIOS, the second one was an issue with it87 kernel module. sensors-detect wanted me to load this module, but it was not loadable (modprobe it87 ended up with **FATAL: Error inserting it87**, so the second line solved it)

I also cleaned the fan and the CPU, although they were not that dusty, but didn't help either.

Although I want to get auto detection running again, I also tried to control it by fancontrol. But unfortunately, this won't work. I get...

```
PWM 255 FAN 0
Fan Stopped at PWM = 255
This fan appears to stop when the PWM is enabled;
perhaps the fan input shares a pin with the PWM output
on the sensor chip.
You cannot control this fan with this PWM output.
```

I already tried to load the previous kernel, but no result.
By the way, my CPU usage is only at 4%, so there are no heavy processes running.

Output of sensors (I'm not sure why those ISA adapters have these strange values. Maybe it's a part of the problem?)

```
$ sensors
it8720-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in1:          +1.63 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in2:          +0.54 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
+5V:          +3.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in4:          +4.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in5:          +4.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
in6:          +4.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
5VSB:         +3.95 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
Vbat:         +3.42 V  
fan1:        3375 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:        1310 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:        1303 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +40.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +38.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high =  -9.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:       -128.0°C  (low  =  -1.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = disabled
cpu0_vid:    +0.613 V
intrusion0:  OK

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +39.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +90.0°C, hyst = +88.0°C)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the temperature and fan speed with `sensors`, and boot from the livecd and try there to see if it is different.

Comment: It's the same with a livecd and I extended the question by sensors data.

Comment: Then it doesn't look like it has anything to do with software.  The bearings are probably going bad.  Unless you changed any settings in the bios relating to the fan.

Comment: You were right, it was the bearings. Changed the fan and it's much quieter although I'm not very satisfied with it, because it's much louder than my old one. Maybe I should get another one.

Comment: Ok, seems that I made a mistake, the CPU fan is even quieter than my old one, but I put it accidentally upside down onto the socket, so the thermometry was not in contact with the cooling ribs. Since I changed it again, it's very quiet now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appeared to be a faulty hardware issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Psusi was right, the bearing of the fan was broken (I felt it as I rotated the fan with the finger). I changed the fan, no noise anymore.